# jquery to find img size and set to div css height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to get jquery to find the size of each image (between 8-10 images per page) in an owl carousel. For some reason, in the developer I just get back `width 0px, height: 0px`

here are the elements as they appear from developer:

```
<div class="item" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
    <img src="url.com/img.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

my jquery:

```
$('.item').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        w = $this.find('img').width(), 
        h = $this.find('img').height();
    $this.width(w).height(h); 
});
```

how can i manage jquery to get the size of the image as it loads?

Comment: Your image isn't loaded yet so no size ofcourse

Comment: is there a way to delay it till after the image loads?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to wait till the image is loaded before you query for its height and width.

Code snippet follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {  /* Just added this part */
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $img = $this.find('img');

      $img.load(function(){
         var w = $this.find('img').width();
         var h = $this.find('img').height();
        alert("width: " + w + " & height: " + h);
        $this.width(w).height(h)
      });

    ;
  });
}); /* Just added this part */
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x100/000/fff.png
" alt="" />
</div>
```

Jquery ready function fires after the dom is ready and not after making sure the image is loaded.https://api.jquery.com/ready/.

Comment: Sai's answer is wrong. As it does not wait for the image to be loaded. I am unable to add it as a comment so this post

Comment: Only reason it will seem to work in your browser is because the browser has already cached the image. Try clearing the browser cache and running the code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fire your script after all the DOM elements are loaded. That is a good practice as well. Since you are using jQuery, just use the `.ready()` event to fire the script.

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/yk9px6am/5/)**

Code snippet follows,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.item').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      pic = $this.find('img');
    if (pic.load) {
      var w = pic.width();
      var h = pic.height();
      $this.width(w).height(h);

    } else {
      return;
    }

  });
  alert("width : " + $('.item').width() + " & height : " + $('.item').height());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item" style="width: 0px; height: 0px;">
  <img src="http://dummyimage.com/190x100/000/fff.png
" alt="" />
</div>
```

Hope this helps. **Happy Coding :)**

**UPDATE::**

Another updated [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/svaidhyanath/yk9px6am/4/)

This time i added a dummy `div` element and gave that div the height and width of the `item` div.

**Update #2::** You need to wait until atleast the image to load before you can run the script that finds out the height and width of the image and applies it to the parent div which in your case is the "item" div. So in case you want to run the script when the image is ready in the DOM tree but dont want to wait for the entire document DOM tree to be ready, then you can use jQuery `.on("DOMready",".item img",function(){});` event function to achieve. I think this is more or less like lazy-load of images

**Another update**:: Updated my answer taking into account that the image may not be loaded when DOM is ready as per reference of these jQuery [.ready()](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) and [.load()](https://api.jquery.com/load/) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

**example**: https://jsfiddle.net/pomfr960/

Try this:

```
$('.item').each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var img = $this.find('img');

    if(!img.length) return;

    img[0].onload = function () {
        var w = img.width(),
            h = img.height();
        $this.width(w).height(h);
    }
});
```